# Harvest two web application in one wix setup

Tags: wix

I want to harvest two web application in one WIX setup. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many ways, most involve editing the .wixproj file. For example, you could use the `HeatDirectory` task to point to the locations where your web applications are built to, and harvest them. That is probably the route I would go.